# How do i use proxy in web3js?

Tags: http, proxy, http-proxy, web3js

I'm currently using this method to connect to web3js

```
const Web3 = require('web3');
const web3 = new Web3("https://eth-mainnet.alchemyapi.io/v2/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
```

how i can use http proxy , with user and pass
like ip:port:user:pass